# Table doesn't have primary key (MissingPrimaryKeyException)

Tags: c#

I am working on a shopping cart and I got this MissingPrimaryKeyException (Table doesn't have primary key) when using Find() method and I am puzzled what is wrong when I already set a primary key to the data table.

My code for create cart and add to cart:

```
public static void CreateShopCart()
{
        // create a Data Table object to store shopping cart data
        DataTable shoppingCartDataTable = new DataTable("Cart");

        shoppingCartDataTable.Columns.Add("ProductID", typeof(int));
        // make ProductID primary key
        DataColumn[] primaryKeys = new DataColumn[1];
        primaryKeys[0] = shoppingCartDataTable.Columns[0];
        shoppingCartDataTable.PrimaryKey = primaryKeys;

        shoppingCartDataTable.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));
        shoppingCartDataTable.Columns.Add("UnitPrice", typeof(decimal));
        shoppingCartDataTable.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
        shoppingCartDataTable.Columns.Add("ProductDescription", typeof(string));
        shoppingCartDataTable.Columns.Add("SellerUsername", typeof(string));
        shoppingCartDataTable.Columns.Add("Picture", typeof(string));
        // store Data Table in Session
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] = shoppingCartDataTable;
}

public static void AddShopCartItem(int ProductID, decimal Price, string strPName, string strPDesc, string strSellerUsername, string strImage)
{
    int intQty = 1;
    var retStatus  = HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"];
    if (retStatus == null)
        CreateShopCart();

    // get shopping data from Session
    DataTable shoppingCartDataTable = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"];

    //  Find if ProductID already exists in Shopping Cart

    DataRow dr1 = shoppingCartDataTable.Rows.Find(ProductID); **<- This is the line giving the error** 
    if (dr1 != null)
    {
        // ProductID exists. Add quantity to cart 
        intQty = (int)dr1["Quantity"];
        intQty += 1; // increment 1 unit to be ordered
        dr1["Quantity"] = intQty; // store back into session
    }
    else
    {
        // ProductID does not exist; create a new record
        DataRow dr = shoppingCartDataTable.NewRow();
        dr["ProductID"] = ProductID;
        dr["ProductName"] = strPName;
        dr["ProductDescription"] = strPDesc;
        dr["Quantity"] = intQty;
        dr["UnitPrice"] = Price;
        dr["SellerUsername"] = strSellerUsername;
        dr["Picture"] = strImage;
        shoppingCartDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    // store back shopping cart in session
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] = shoppingCartDataTable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have named the columns to add as primary key using  `<ProductID>` while the column name is simply `ProductID`. Strangely there is no error in this syntax (at least testing your code with LinqPAD) but if you try to print the PrimaryKey after the add you will see that there is no PrimaryKey defined.

So, this code

```
DataColumn[] primaryKeys = new DataColumn[1];
primaryKeys[0] = shoppingCartDataTable.Columns["<ProductID>"];
shoppingCartDataTable.PrimaryKey = primaryKeys;
foreach(DataColumn dc in shoppingCartDataTable.PrimaryKey)
    Console.WriteLine(dc.ColumnName);
```

doesn't produce any output

Fix simply adding the PrimaryKey with

```
 DataColumn[] primaryKeys = new DataColumn[1];
 primaryKeys[0] = shoppingCartDataTable.Columns["ProductID"];
 shoppingCartDataTable.PrimaryKey = primaryKeys;
 foreach(DataColumn dc in shoppingCartDataTable.PrimaryKey)
     Console.WriteLine(dc.ColumnName);
```

Prints the ColumnName

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong coding. It should be primaryKeys[0] = shoppingCartDataTable.Columns[0]; I tried your method, unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you try to debug your code and check if (before adding the table to the Session), the primarykey is correctly defined? and, if after retrieving the table from the Session the PrimaryKey is still there?. I have tried with a reduced version of your code  (no Session involved) and nothing strange happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have been figuring out the whole day and found out I made a blunder, I have not called out the CreateShopCart method, which is why the AddShopCartItem method does not have a primary key in the table.

Cheers and thanks for helping.